# One page search result using ajax in magento

Tags: php, ajax, magento

I'm using magento 1.9 C.E, and I want to remove pagination from catalog search result page. I want all the results to be coming on the same page itself with ajax. On click of load more or something the next page result will load that is will get appended to this result page. Can anyone give any idea on how to acheive this one.